# Spinors and forms

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, spin-geometry

In this link http://benasque.org/2009gph/talks_contr/074Herdeiro.pdf page 15, it was said that:

"Use spinorial geometry techniques:
 One takes the space of Dirac spinors to be the space of complexified
forms on $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is spanned over $\mathbb{C}$ by {${1, e_1,e_2,e_{12}}$}."

Though this has to do a little with physics but mainly the requirements are from mathematics. Why is it that we can take the space of Dirac spinors to be the space of complexified forms? And why on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is spanned over $\mathbb{C}$ in this case?

Comment: Dirac spinors are a representation of the Clifford algebra. If you have a physics background, you might be used to the algebra being given in terms of Dirac matrices, but any objects satisfying the correct anticommutation relations $\{ \Gamma^a, \Gamma^b \} = 2 \eta^{ab}$ determine a Clifford algebra. As it says on the same page, you can identify the Gamma matrices with the action of interior and exterior product on differential forms - $\Gamma^a = \sqrt{2} e^a \wedge$ et cetera. It follows that the Dirac spinors are differential forms themselves.